# Quantum computer measurement

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer

Hello Stackexchange physics,
This question is mostly a request for a source of information on quantum measurement and decoherence that is consistent and independent of the particular context.

When I read about quantum information in the context of quantum computers and play with the IBMQ, it appears I can get my entangled state to likely collapse into an arbitrary classical state upon measurement. Without that, quantum computers would just be random noise generators.

Yet when I try to find more about quantum information and measurement (like the answers Stackexchange is recommending I check first before posting) I get a different story. They insist entangled quantum states collapse into seemingly random classical states, and that Bob and Alice must compare notes to notice the correlation.

What is the difference between IBMQ's and Bob and Alice's measurements? Is IBMQ comparing notes classically like Bob and Alice have to? **Strictly speaking are they even doing the same operations?**

I also notice that people purposefully measure on an orthogonal basis to the state vector; isn't that choice what ensures the outcome, not what preceded it?

A source of information or some direction that can help bridge the gap would be appreciated,
thank you.